# A connection attempt failed [ASP .Net Core, IIS]

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, proxy, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.1

I host the ASP.NET Core (3.0) Web Application in IIS. The application works in my development environment and also in a docker image inside a linux machine.

Now I tried to host the application as well in IIS and now struggle with the following error message, when I try to call a external REST API:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I'm quite sure this is a proxy problem. Regarding this I tried different solutions, but nothing worked for me:

**Added ForwardedHeadersOptions**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{    
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
    });    
}
```

**Added UseCertificateForwarding before UseAuthorization**

```
   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
        app.UseCertificateForwarding();
        app.UseAuthorization();
   }
```

**Added the Proxy in the web.config file**

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy
        proxyaddress="http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX"
        bypassonlocal="true"
      />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

Does anyone has an idea, what I can try next?

Comment: .NET Core does not pick up proxy settings from `web.config`, so you have to use other approaches (environment variables like `HTTP_PROXY`, registry keys or others).

Comment: @LexLi thank you very much! Thats the answer :)